# Getting an average of each column from CSV

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the average of all the columns in CSV with respect to timestamp. The object type is system.array. Whenever I try to convert the integer it is showing an error.

```
timestamp   streams TRP A   B   C   D 
6/4/2019    6775    305 56  229 132 764
6/4/2019    6910    316 28  356 118 134
6/4/2019    6749    316 54  218 206 144
6/5/2019    5186    267 84  280 452 258
6/5/2019    5187    240 33  436 455 245
6/5/2019    5224    291 21  245 192 654
6/6/2019    5254    343 42  636 403 789
6/6/2019    5180    252 23  169 328 888
6/6/2019    5181    290 32  788 129 745
6/6/2019    5244    328 44  540 403 989
```

I got help from Lee_Dailey on the below code, I was trying to produce the average of each column based on timestamp. I get an error

```
Cannot convert value " " to type "System.Int32".
Error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
+ ... l = [Math]::Round(($GIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.ForEach({[int]$_}) | Mea ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

```bsh
$InStuff = Import-Csv 'M:\MyDoc\script\logfiles\Output_18Mar\streams_E1WAF2_OUTPUT.csv'
$TargetPropertyList = $InStuff[0].PSObject.Properties.Name.Where({$_ - ne 'TimeStamp'})

$GroupedInStuff = $InStuff | Group-Object -Property TimeStamp
$Results = foreach ($GIS_Item in $GroupedInStuff) {
    $HighestValues = [ordered]@{
        TimeStamp = $GIS_Item.Name
    }
    foreach ($TPL_Item in $TargetPropertyList) {
        $TempHiVal = [Math]::Round(($GIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.ForEach({[int]$_}) | Measure-Object -Average).Average)
        $HighestValues.Add($TPL_Item, $TempHiVal)
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$HighestValues
}
$Results = $Results | Sort-Object -Property {[DateTime]$_.TimeStamp}
```

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I have posted the new question. I was not able to get the desired output which I tried. But no luck

Comment: when i run that code, it works with the sample data you provided. [*grin*] also, i somehow managed to leave off the `, 2` that should end the `$TempHiVal =` line - the code you posted give integers - with the added `, 2` you get `1.33` instead of `1` for the `G` column of the `6/5/2019` row. ///// so ... [1] what is the FULL error msg - it usually includes the line number. [2] does the code you posted work with the sample data you posted on your system?

Comment: Hi lee, @Lee_Dailey I am actually trying to import a csv, it works well with sample data but not with CSV. I think it has something to do with the datatype cast.

Comment: try outputting the object to your screen with errors set to STOP. that otta let you see the data that triggers the glitch. if you can show me that, then i can add a filter to remove or ignore it. perhaps just a ` remove all non-digits` would do the job, but i want to be sure the problem is where it seems to be. [*grin*]

Comment: CSV is a plain text format. Please show your raw CSV data (open the file(s) with a text editor and copy/paste the text) rather than what you see when you open the file in Excel. With that said, the error you're getting suggests that you have a field with spurious whitespace somewhere in your data.

Comment: your new data set has lots of extra spaces. for instance, the property names now have spaces in them. lookee >>> `$InStuff[0].'A '` <<< that space after the `A` is part of the prop name. that throws off the property/data alignment. the data in the props ALSO has spaces in it. so, is the data you show the LITERAL content of the CSV file? it's unusual to see a trailing delimiter, for one thing.

Comment: I have tried to paste it from CSV. Please ignore the spaces. Not sure if still is formatted properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a way to deal with the somewhat damaged CSV file you presented in the new data set. [*grin*] it reads the file in as *plain text*, removes the spaces, and trims the final `|`.

i was wondering if having only one date in a grouping was a problem, so i added a final line to the data set that has a different date.

```
# fake reading in a defective CSV file as plain text
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
timestamp|abc | A     |  B  |  C   |   D  |  E   |  F  |  G    |
6/4/2019 |6775 |  3059 |  4  | 2292 | 1328 | 764  |  0 |  0  |
6/4/2019 |6910 |  3167 |  28 | 3568 | 1180 | 1348 |  0 |  0  |
6/4/2019 |6749 |  3161 |  0  | 2180 | 2060 | 1440 |  0 |  28 |
6/5/2019 |6738 |  3118 |  4  | 2736 | 1396 | 984  |  0 |  0  |
6/5/2019 |6718 |  3130 |  12 | 3076 | 1008 | 452  |  0 |  4  |
6/5/2019 |6894 |  3046 |  4  | 2284 | 1556 | 624  |  0 |  0  |
1/1/2021 |1111 |  2222 |  3  | 4444 | 5555 | 666  |  7 |  8  |
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$CleanedInStuff = $InStuff.ForEach({$_.Replace(' ', '').Trim('|')}) |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'

$TargetPropertyList = $CleanedInStuff[0].PSObject.Properties.Name.
    Where({
        $_ -ne 'TimeStamp'
        })

$GroupedCIS = $CleanedInStuff |
    Group-Object -Property TimeStamp

$Results = foreach ($GCIS_Item in $GroupedCIS) {
    $TempObject = [ordered]@{
        TimeStamp = $GCIS_Item.Name
    }
    foreach ($TPL_Item in $TargetPropertyList) {
        $TempAveValue = [Math]::Round(($GCIS_Item.Group.$TPL_Item.
            ForEach({[int]$_}) |
            Measure-Object -Average).Average, 2)
        $TempObject.Add($TPL_Item, $TempAveValue)
    }

    [PSCustomObject]$TempObject
}

$Results = $Results |
    Sort-Object -Property {
        [DateTime]$_.TimeStamp
        }

$Results
```

output ...

```
TimeStamp : 6/4/2019
abc       : 6811.33
A         : 3129
B         : 10.67
C         : 2680
D         : 1522.67
E         : 1184
F         : 0
G         : 9.33

TimeStamp : 6/5/2019
abc       : 6783.33
A         : 3098
B         : 6.67
C         : 2698.67
D         : 1320
E         : 686.67
F         : 0
G         : 1.33

TimeStamp : 1/1/2021
abc       : 1111
A         : 2222
B         : 3
C         : 4444
D         : 5555
E         : 666
F         : 7
G         : 8
```

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey,it still shows the same error. I am not sure what I am missing. 
Cannot convert value " " to type "System.Int32". Error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @BijoDev - [1]did you read the file in with `Get-Content` and let the cleanup code remove the spaces? [2] what shows in `$CleanedInStuff` and in `$TargetPropertyList`? [3] is the same line giving an error? [4] did you use my exact code or did you modify your previous code?

Comment: My data is in CSV, the sample data which I showed was just to structure it. So I didn't use the variable $CleanedInStuff because I am directing importing it from CSV file. But it still shows the error.

Comment: so sorry, actually I tried to copy the data from csv. But it was not formatted properly. That's the reason I have add these delimeters to order it in a tabular format. :(

Comment: @BijoDev - don't bother to make it pretty. just post the realistic data. no one can accurately script for something that doesn't match the sample data.

Comment: I have modified the csv data. Please ignore the spaces. I tried copying the exact input from csv. I am not sure why the error is coming again and again and that too for the type cast.

Comment: @BijoDev - that is not a CSV file. [*grin*] it seems to be a fixed-column  data file. that means your `Import-CSV` command is not working. have you tried looking at what you have in `$InStuff` immediately after you import that file?

Comment: @BijoDev - also, there is an error in your posted code - you have a space after the dash in `-ne` of your 2nd line.

Comment: @BijoDev - this >>> `$InStuff = (Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\Temp\BijoDev_BadCSV_File.csv") -replace ' {1,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv` <<< will read in the file you posted, replace one-or-more spaces with a comma, and then convert it the same way that `Import-CSV` would do with a correct CSV file.

Comment: it's the same CSV file from which we sorted the highest values. But it doesn't works when exporting the average values for each column.

Comment: Thank you so much , it works fine. There wasn't any issues with the csv. The code worked fine. My error preference were the issues. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a nicer way to do this that Lee will surely advise, but this is how I would complete the task. This will group the objects by the `Timestamp` property and then you can average them there. I recommend playing around with `$csv | Group-Object timestamp` and see what you can do with it.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\temp\test.csv
$Averages = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Foreach($object in ($csv | Group-Object timestamp)) {

    $Averages.Add([pscustomobject]@{
        timestamp = $object.Name
        abc = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty abc | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        a = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty a | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        b = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty b | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        c = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty c | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        d = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty d | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        e = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty e | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        f = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty f | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        g = ($object.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty g | Measure-Object -Average).Average
        })
}
```

Output:

```
PS H:\> $Averages


timestamp : 6/4/2019
abc       : 6811.33333333333
a         : 3129
b         : 10.6666666666667
c         : 2680
d         : 1522.66666666667
e         : 1184
f         : 0
g         : 9.33333333333333

timestamp : 6/5/2019
abc       : 6783.33333333333
a         : 3098
b         : 6.66666666666667
c         : 2698.66666666667
d         : 1320
e         : 686.666666666667
f         : 0
g         : 1.33333333333333
```

Comment: hah! the code the OP shows actually works with the data set provided. i suspect the problem is the real data set that is being used.

Comment: Classic, I didn't even try running the original with the sample provided honestly. CSV data is probably string and not int, you got this my dude.

Comment: yep the OP needs to show the data sample that glitches the process. adding a filter to remove non-digits is easy ... but not needed with the current data set.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet I created is actually supposed to read fixed width column tables but there isn't any reason why it shouldn't be able to also read delimited (or distorted) tables. So this question has encouraged me to create an update which no longer produces errors when this happens.

### Converting the table in the question

```
$Table = '
    timestamp   streams TRP A   B   C   D 
    6/4/2019    6775    305 56  229 132 764
    6/4/2019    6910    316 28  356 118 134
    6/4/2019    6749    316 54  218 206 144
    6/5/2019    5186    267 84  280 452 258
    6/5/2019    5187    240 33  436 455 245
    6/5/2019    5224    291 21  245 192 654
    6/6/2019    5254    343 42  636 403 789
    6/6/2019    5180    252 23  169 328 888
    6/6/2019    5181    290 32  788 129 745
    6/6/2019    5244    328 44  540 403 989
'

# Raw Table
ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Table | Format-Table

timestamp streams TRP A  B   C   D
--------- ------- --- -  -   -   -
6/4/2019  6775    305 56 229 132 764
6/4/2019  6910    316 28 356 118 134
6/4/2019  6749    316 54 218 206 144
6/5/2019  5186    267 84 280 452 258
6/5/2019  5187    240 33 436 455 245
6/5/2019  5224    291 21 245 192 654
6/6/2019  5254    343 42 636 403 789
6/6/2019  5180    252 23 169 328 888
6/6/2019  5181    290 32 788 129 745
6/6/2019  5244    328 44 540 403 989

#Streamed rows from pipeline:
$Table -split [System.Environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Format-Table

timestamp streams TRP A  B   C   D
--------- ------- --- -  -   -   -
6/4/2019  6775    305 56 229 132 764
6/4/2019  6910    316 28 356 118 134
6/4/2019  6749    316 54 218 206 144
6/5/2019  5186    267 84 280 452 258
6/5/2019  5187    240 33 436 455 245
6/5/2019  5224    291 21 245 192 654
6/6/2019  5254    343 42 636 403 789
6/6/2019  5180    252 23 169 328 888
6/6/2019  5181    290 32 788 129 745
6/6/2019  5244    328 44 540 403 989
```

### Fixed width column table with vertical rulers

```
$Table = '
    | date      |  abc |    A |  B |    C |    D |    E |  F |  G |
    | 6/4/2019  | 6775 | 3059 |  4 | 2292 | 1328 |  764 |  0 |  0 |
    | 6/4/2019  | 6910 | 3167 | 28 | 3568 | 1180 | 1348 |  0 |  0 |
    | 6/4/2019  | 6749 | 3161 |  0 | 2180 | 2060 | 1440 |  0 | 28 |
    | 6/5/2019  | 6738 | 3118 |  4 | 2736 | 1396 |  984 |  0 |  0 |
    | 6/5/2019  | 6718 | 3130 | 12 | 3076 | 1008 |  452 |  0 |  4 |
    | 6/5/2019  | 6894 | 3046 |  4 | 2284 | 1556 |  624 |  0 |  0 |
    | 1/1/2021  | 1111 | 2222 |  3 | 4444 | 5555 |  666 |  7 |  8 |
'

# Raw Table
ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Table | Format-Table

date      abc    A  B    C    D    E F  G
----      ---    -  -    -    -    - -  -
6/4/2019 6775 3059  4 2292 1328  764 0  0
6/4/2019 6910 3167 28 3568 1180 1348 0  0
6/4/2019 6749 3161  0 2180 2060 1440 0 28
6/5/2019 6738 3118  4 2736 1396  984 0  0
6/5/2019 6718 3130 12 3076 1008  452 0  4
6/5/2019 6894 3046  4 2284 1556  624 0  0
1/1/2021 1111 2222  3 4444 5555  666 7  8

#Streamed rows from pipeline:
$Table -split [System.Environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Format-Table

date      abc    A  B    C    D    E F  G
----      ---    -  -    -    -    - -  -
6/4/2019 6775 3059  4 2292 1328  764 0  0
6/4/2019 6910 3167 28 3568 1180 1348 0  0
6/4/2019 6749 3161  0 2180 2060 1440 0 28
6/5/2019 6738 3118  4 2736 1396  984 0  0
6/5/2019 6718 3130 12 3076 1008  452 0  4
6/5/2019 6894 3046  4 2284 1556  624 0  0
1/1/2021 1111 2222  3 4444 5555  666 7  8
```

<sub>Note the type casting (table alignment) in the results, meaning that the result is symmetrical:

`$Result = $Table | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Format-Table`

`$Result | Format-Table` <=> `$Result | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Format-Table`</sub>

### Distorted table

```
$Table = '
    timestamp|abc | A     |  B  |  C   |   D  |  E   |  F  |  G    |
    6/4/2019 |6775 |  3059 |  4  | 2292 | 1328 | 764  |  0 |  0  |
    6/4/2019 |6910 |  3167 |  28 | 3568 | 1180 | 1348 |  0 |  0  |
    6/4/2019 |6749 |  3161 |  0  | 2180 | 2060 | 1440 |  0 |  28 |
    6/5/2019 |6738 |  3118 |  4  | 2736 | 1396 | 984  |  0 |  0  |
    6/5/2019 |6718 |  3130 |  12 | 3076 | 1008 | 452  |  0 |  4  |
    6/5/2019 |6894 |  3046 |  4  | 2284 | 1556 | 624  |  0 |  0  |
    1/1/2021 |1111 |  2222 |  3  | 4444 | 5555 | 666  |  7 |  8  |
'
# Raw Table
ConvertFrom-SourceTable $Table | Format-Table

timestamp abc  A    B  C    D    E    F G
--------- ---  -    -  -    -    -    - -
6/4/2019  6775 3059 4  2292 1328 764  0 0
6/4/2019  6910 3167 28 3568 1180 1348 0 0
6/4/2019  6749 3161 0  2180 2060 1440 0 28
6/5/2019  6738 3118 4  2736 1396 984  0 0
6/5/2019  6718 3130 12 3076 1008 452  0 4
6/5/2019  6894 3046 4  2284 1556 624  0 0
1/1/2021  1111 2222 3  4444 5555 666  7 8

#Streamed rows from pipeline:
$Table -split [System.Environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Format-Table

timestamp abc  A    B  C    D    E    F G
--------- ---  -    -  -    -    -    - -
6/4/2019  6775 3059 4  2292 1328 764  0 0
6/4/2019  6910 3167 28 3568 1180 1348 0 0
6/4/2019  6749 3161 0  2180 2060 1440 0 28
6/5/2019  6738 3118 4  2736 1396 984  0 0
6/5/2019  6718 3130 12 3076 1008 452  0 4
6/5/2019  6894 3046 4  2284 1556 624  0 0
1/1/2021  1111 2222 3  4444 5555 666  7 8
```

<sub>Note that distorted rows will always result in a literal (string) conversion (no type casting)</sub>